# Laravel Form not working: controller is not called

Tags: laravel, forms

I've been stuck with this issue for serveral hours, so hopefully some of you can help. Thanks in advance.

The issue is simple: when I click the form's submit button, nothing happens. Like, literally nothing. No errors, anything. 
Before starting developing the form I had created the Message model by doing

```
php artisan make:model Message --resource
```

Thus I have the methods create, store etc.. already done and ready (thanks artisan!).
In my route web.php route file, I have:

```
Route::resource('Message','MessageController');
```

This should automatically link all the methods, right?

Anyway, my form is:

```
{!!  Form::open(['action' => 'MessageController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                                    <ul class="row">
                                        <li class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label>{{Form::label('name','Name')}}</label>
                                                {{Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col-sm-6">
                                            <label>{{Form::label('email','Email')}}</label>
                                                {{Form::text('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your email'])}}
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="col-sm-12">
                                            <label>{{Form::label('message','Message')}}</label>
                                                {{Form::textarea('message','', ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
                                        </li>
                                        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn-round'])}}

                                    </ul>
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

and my MessageController@store looks like this:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this -> validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
            ]
            );

        $message = new Message();
        $message -> name= $request -> input('name');
        $message -> email= $request -> input('email');
        $message -> text= $request ->input('text');
        $message -> user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $message->save();

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

The controller just doesn't seem to work because even if I cut validation, nothing happens. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: If you inspect the network tab in the browser can you see if the request gets fired?

Comment: Just add @csrf token, because while using POST Method csrf token is required. In your case add {!! Form::token() !!}

Comment: Your route might be having capital `M` in url/Message/create etc as your resource declaration in routes contains `Message`. Please check

Answer (score 0):

you must use route.

In HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('login')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

In route/web.php:

```
Route::post('login','WelcomeController@log_in');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all make sure your route is correctly defined by running:

```
php artisan route:list
```

you should see a table contains all routes listed with their names, routes, controllers.
you should see six routes for Message, the one we are seeking for now is 'message.store'

I see you are using laravel collective to render your form, are you sure its rendered correctly? does it render DOM elements with the correct route for form action and correct names for textareas? simply inspect from your browser.

if not, you can just try with simple blade view:

```
<form method="POST" action = "{{ route('message.store') }}">
<!-- include CSRF token as the following -->
@CSRF
@if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->get('name') as $error)
            <li>
                {{ $error }}
            </li>
            @endforeach
<input name="name">
@if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->get('email') as $error)
            <li>
                {{ $error }}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
            </span>
        @endif
<input name="email">
@if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="invalid-feedback">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->get('message') as $error)
            <li>
                {{ $error }}
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
            </span>
        @endif
<input name="message">
<submit />
</form>
```

then make sure the post request is fired from DevTools>network.